# mongodb date insert like using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am inserting bulk records in mongodb. I am using the native DB drivers to do this, as the performance is much higher. At other points in my application, i am using mongoose. The problem I am having is that mongoose translates the date into a different format whereas mongodb native just inserts it as the number of seconds since 1970. So later queries in mongoose based off that date do not work.

Here's my mongoose schema:

```
var MySchema = new Schema({
  name              : { type: String, required: true },
  updatedAt         : Date
});
```

And my mongo db mass insert:

```
var newRec = { 
    name        : entry.Name, 
    updatedAt   : Date.now
};
newRecords.push(newRec);

MySchema.collection.insert(newRecords, function(err, newRecs) {
            res.json(newRecs.ops);
          });
```

This produces in the DB:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "562818ecf24d540f0053a38d"
    },
    "name": "Cool Record",
    "updatedAt": 12312423512
}
```

Whereas if it was run through Mongoose it would produce:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "561fd90285b5e73f5626f74e"
    },
    "name": "Cool Record",
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2015-10-20T20:01:17.553Z"
    }
}
```

If going through mongoose, queries like this work well:

```
MySchemda.find({ updatedAt : { $gt: lastSynced }}).exec();
```

But do not work otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

`Date.now` is a *number* representing milliseconds since 1970. While it conceptually represents a date, it isn't actually a `Date`:

```
var x = Date.now;
typeof x;
// "number"
```

You need to switch your schema to be:

```
var MySchema = new Schema({
    name              : { type: String, required: true },
    updatedAt         : Number
});
```

alternately, you can use:

```
var newRec = {
    name: entry.Name,
    updatedAt: new Date()
}
```

and keep your schema as it is.

Answer (score -1):

You may use it like this:
Define the date type and the default value, then create a variable which can be defined as your schema use `year : new Date` this would help a lot to set the date.

```
var songSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name : String,
year : {type : Date, default : Date.now}, 
singer : String,
});
var song  = mongoose.model("song", songSchema);
var xyz= new song({
name : "abcd",
year :new Date,  // to set the date first set new Date
singer : "aabbccdd",
});
```

You can use setDate , setMonth, setYear method to solve the issues.There are more methods  defined under the object year .You can out further at the documentation of mongoose.

```
xyz.save(function(err, songs){
if(err) 
winston.log("Something is wrong"+ "   "+ err);
else {
songs.year.setDate(03); 
songs.year.setMonth(03);
songs.year.setYear(2015);
winston.log(songs);
}
});
```